# "Union" based file manager

Tags: files, directory, thunar, ranger

I would like to be able to perform actions on files in different locations within a common window/container. Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
└── DCIM
    ├── browser-photos
    │    ├── merel.jpg
    │    ├── yent.jpg
    │    └── raha.jpg
    └── Camera
        ├── laki.jpg
        ├── wion.jpg
        ├── darta.jpg
        ├── qonad.jpg
        ├── isha.jpg
        ├── mowi.jpg
        └── kaens.jpg

3 directories, 10 files
```

Is it possible for me to start a file manager like `Thunar` or `Ranger` in a way that would let me view all 10 files on a single level (no nesting), and when I perform an action on a single file (e.g. remove) — it's performed within the file's location.

This isn't just for images. I'm currently going through a few old hard drives and I'm spending a lot of time traversing through unnecessary hierarchies.

Comment: What is **your** meaning of “window/container”?

Comment: Dolphin (part of KDE), lets you view the files as you have shown them in the question. I often view them like that, to avoid traversal.

Comment: @richard the part of the GUI where the files are shown, whether it's console based (e.g. Ranger) or X based (e.g. Thunar).

Comment: You can use midnight commander and find files with regex *, then you'll get all files on one panel. In x you can use pcmanfm and a similar find.